# Can a Couchbase application work with no network connection (like CouchDB)?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

I'm building an application where users running android tablets will have to be able to write to a database (running on their local device) with NO network connection and sync using peer-to-peer replication (through a USB connection or possibly bluetooth). I'm working in West Africa, where internet is basically nonexistent.

I know that CouchDB will work for this use case, but it seems like it's difficult to get CouchDB running on Android (compared to Couchbase). Will Couchbase work for this project?

Thanks!
- avi

Comment: Why not use SQLite? Use a built-in storage option, if possible! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: couchbase has an embedded mode now.

Comment: PouchDB seems relevant here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PM from Couchbase here. We've actually been working on an embedded NoSQL database for mobile dubbed "Couchbase Lite" (in parallel with SQL and SQLite) that plays exactly into the scenario you are describing. The idea is to provide your application with a JSON-based database that can:

- Opportunistically sync to a backend cluster as needed
- Utilize our built-in P2P support to replicate data between devices without going through a central point
- Store data locally in its original JSON format for full-offline access to your data

Some initial reading can be found here (http://www.couchbase.com/mobile#lite) but feel free to get in touch with me if you'd like to discuss more in-depth.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jessica! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for offering to get in touch; I'll read through the initial readings, and will contact you if I have any questions or would like to discuss further.